# How to populate tableview in xcode from soap results

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, soap

I have a soap result with this form:

```
<root>
  <a> 
    <b> string </b>
    <c> int</c>
    <d> string </d>
  </a>
  <a> 
    <b> string </b>
    <c> int</c>
    <d> string </d>
  </a> /......
```

So can anyone tell me how to populate tableview?

Answer (score 0):

Parse the value in tags  "b","c","d" store in a dictionary then add parsed content between "a" tag in an array. Display that in TableView.
If you are not familiar with XML parsing in objective -C search for NSXMLParser or XML parsing objective-C iphone in google.com